# Chrome's emulate touch screen circle not visible

Tags: windows, google-chrome, touch

I have a strange issue whit my emulate touch functionality on Google Chrome version 49.0.2623.110 m.
I'm using laptop + monitor (both Dell) and running Windows 8. 
The issue is that while Chrome is on my secondary monitor and touch screen emulation is enabled I cannot see a touch screen pointer (black circle) nor any kind of pointer, but when I move my Chrome to my main laptop display it would show. I tried disabling laptop display while using external monitor and it is the same, I cannot see the pointer. This was not a problem with previous Chrome version.

Did anyone had similar issues with this version?

Thank you

EDIT:
I've change the laptop, updated to win10 and updated Chrome to 50.0.2661.87 m version and I still have the same issue (colleague of mine has the same problem as well).

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine "solved" the problem by enabling Windows' Mouse pointer trails at minimum length. I find it too annoying to work with the setting enable, but it does work if you really need it.

[Mouse settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psZy5.png)

Answer (score 0):

They did some changes in recent version of Dev Tools and some options are now gone. Ensure you have "Mobile" or "Desktop with touch" selected, as you can see on the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: When I use only Desktop I get normal mouse pointer but when I enable touch (and I need this for testing my app) cursor disappears ass soon as I hover over the app.